# Al visualizar el gráfico hecho en Dash y plotly, los valores se muestran comprimidos en el eje X

Tags: python, plotly, dash

Estoy iniciándome en el uso de dash y plotly. Veo que los valores se me muestran comprimidos en el eje X.

```
dbc.Row([
            html.Div(
                dbc.Col([
                    html.Label("Error Status Trends"),
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id = 'plot1',
                        figure = {
                    'data':[
                            go.Scatter(
                                x = [1,2,3,4,5],
                                y = [1,2,3,4,5],
                                mode = 'markers',
                                marker={'size':7,
                                        'opacity':0.5,
                                        'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}})],
                    'layout': go.Layout(
                            title="Gráfico de línea",
                            xaxis={'title': 'Valores de X'},
                            yaxis={'title': 'Valores de Y'})}
                )
                    ],style={'width':"100%",'margin':'auto'})),
                ])
```

Aquí la imagen del gráfico que se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]